# Android App stops responding for SQLCipher

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite, android-database, sqlcipher-android

I have just changed my database from SQLite to SQLCipher. And my app became unbelievably slow. It takes ages to take click actions.
I studied and found out these two possible reasons:

- **Do not repeatedly open and close connections, as key derivation is very expensive, by design. Frequent opening / closing of the database connection (e.g. for every query) is a very common cause of performance issues that can usually be easily resolved using a singleton database connection.**
- **Use transactions to wrap insert / update / delete operations. Unless executed in a transaction scope, every operation will occur within it's own transaction which slows things down by several orders of magnitude.**

About the first point, Can some one please explain what does it mean by opening and closing connections repeatedly. I think me using `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase("secure_key);` for every Query is the problem. Any example on How can I use a singleton database connection class for this will be a great help.

About the second point, how can I use wrapper for the mentioned queries and will it be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to point 1) the following code, within the `DBHelper`, creates a singleton connection (note I only close the db in the Main Activity's `onDestroy` method).

```
/**
 * Instantiates a new Db helper.
 *
 * @param context the context
 */
DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

private static DBHelper instance;

/**
 * Gets helper.
 *
 * @param context the context
 * @return the helper
 */
static synchronized DBHelper getHelper(Context context) {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new DBHelper(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

and you use the following to get your helper :-

```
    dbhelper = DBHelper.getHelper(context);
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

With regard to 2 you use, `db.beginTransaction();` to begin a transaction,  `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` to mark it as successful after making the DB changes (**this is required in order for the transaction to be applied. Otherwise, ending the transaction will effectively negate any changes applied**) and          `db.endTransaction();` to complete the transaction.
Note that transactions don't nest, so when nesting transactions you have to add code so that the `beginTransaction`, `setTransactionSuccessfull` and `endTransaction` are only applied once.

The follow is an example that caters for nesting :-

```
 void deleteAisle(long aisleid, boolean intransaction) {

    if (doesAisleExist(aisleid)) {
        if (!intransaction) {
            db.beginTransaction();
        }

        String whereargs[] = {Long.toString(aisleid)};
        // Delete ProductUsage rows that have Aisle as a parent
        pudeletes = db.delete(
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_TABLE,
                DBProductusageTableConstants.PRODUCTUSAGE_AISLEREF_COL +
                        " = ?",
                whereargs
        );

       // More done here but removed for brevity (including deletion of the Aisle)

        if (!intransaction) {
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
            msg = "DB Transacion SET and ENDED for Aisle ID=" + Long.toString(aisleid);

        }
    }
}
```

The above may be called individually but if deleting a shop then it could be called multiple times, in which case it would be called with **intransaction ** being true (so the `beginTransaction`, `setTransactionSuccessful` and `endTransaction` would be skipped and left to be done by the parent).

As for usefulness, you'd only use transactions if doing a number of actions together.